# How can I run BATS tests from Gradle?

Tags: gradle, automated-tests, gradle-plugin

I would like to use the [BATS framework](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats) from Gradle. Is there a way to do it, or does it require developing a new plugin? It doesn't seem to appear on the [plugins page](https://plugins.gradle.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Using the examples from https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html you can make your own a task to execute bates like so:

```
task runBats(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '../dirWithMyBats'
  //on windows:
  commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'bats', 'myBats.bats'
  // OR on linux
  commandLine 'bats', 'myBats.bats'
}
```

And then just run the task via: `gradle runbats` or make another grade task depend on this one.

If `bats mybats.bat` fails then the task and build will fail.